# How Import txt file with xml responses in google sheets with Google apps script?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

I have a log.txt file with records with this structure:

```
20190509 131952 CON  Parametros: [abc....]
20190509 131952 CON  Changing Endpoint to https:.....
20190509 131952 INF  SQL: select .....
20190509 131952 CON  Outbound with header: 
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.........</S:Envelope>
```

I just wanted to extract the lines with the xml response
`<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.........</S:Envelope>`
  and import to google sheets with the data in the corresponding column.

I'm not an expert in apps script and I can not see how I can use XmlService to get the result. I think the ideal would be to import the file and for each line validate if it is an xml response if it is import into google sheets.
Thank you if anyone could give me some directions on how to get what I want. I researched but could not find any example of this type.

```
function Importa() {
  var PastaAMonitorizar = DriveApp.getFolderById('abc_xyz'); // id da pasta onde txt está quardado
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('abc_xyz'); //id da folha para onde são importados os dados
  var files = PastaAMonitorizar.getFiles();

  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
    var fileName = file.getName();

    var targetRng = ss.getSheetByName("INFO"),
        fileTextObj = file.getAs('text/plain'),
        fileText = fileTextObj.getDataAsString('ISO-8859-1'),
        lines = fileText.split('\n'),
...
```

I know Import a txt file, but but I can not figure out how to extract only the xml response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Extracting desired data from log.txt**

You need to supply the fileId.

This was my file url: `https://anyfile-notepad.semaan.ca/app#edit/GoogleDrive/1KTusR1iiQQHB1lXQfYDh2MEjDHEOsdNm`

The id is the string after the last forward slash.

```
function extractData() {
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById('fileId');
  var content=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var a1=content.split('\n');
  var a2=a1.filter(function(elem){return (elem.slice(0,1)=='<')});
  return a2;//and array of your desired strings
}
```

[Array.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)

This will display your results in a simple dialog:

```
function extractData() {
  var file=DriveApp.getFileById('fileId');
  var content=file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var a1=content.split('\n');
  var a2=a1.filter(function(elem){return (elem.slice(0,1)=='<')});
  var html='';
  for(var i=0;i<a2.length;i++) {
    html+='<br />' + a2[i].replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(j) {return '&#'+j.charCodeAt(0)+';';})
  }
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Desired Strings')
}
```

This code:`replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';})` provided by @Chris Baker.

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer because although incomplete, pointed me to a solution. Maybe it's not the best, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Cooper's response, I came up with this solution:

```
function extractD() {
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById('xyz_abc');
  var content = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var a1 = content.split('\n').filter(function(elem){return (elem.slice(0,1)=='<')}),
      a11 = [];

  a1 = a1.map(function(x){ return x.replace(/\u003c\u002f/g,"\u003e")});

  a1.forEach(function(y) { a11.push(y.split('\u003e'));}); 

  var a2 = a11.map(function(e){return [e[2].replace('<',''),//A
                                       e[6].slice(0,19).replace('T',' '),//B
                                       e[30],e[31]]});

  Logger.log(a2)
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("abc_xyz").getSheetByName("1").getRange(1, 1,a2.length, a2[0].length)
  .setValues(a2);
}
```

Probably not the best way, but it works and as I did not find another solution, it stays for those who are looking for something similar.